# Clear browser cache after navigation form page

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have a multisite setup, where each site loads it's data via ajax. Everything is working perfect expect one detail. If I press the back button the ajax data is loaded from the browser cache an not from the server. This is problematic, since the user might navigate to a second page, changes a state and navigates back to the previous page where he want's to see the change in the overview (e.g. the accepted tasks chart now has one more accepted task because he accepted it).

1. The most common solution I found **is adding a time stamp to the ajax
   request** (in jQuery via the `cache: false` property). However this
   has the disadvantage that it disables the http caching (statuscode
   304) which I don't want to do. Also I need the 304 statuscode to not
   update my view in other scenarios.
2. The second option is binding the **`window.onbeforeunload`** and display
   a warning message when the user leaves the page. This invalidates the browser cache so the request is  done (without adding a timestamp) even when the back button is
   pressed. The disadvantage is, that the user gets a confirmation dialog
   every time he navigates from the page (which is very annoying). For
   security reasons I can't confirm it via JavaScript, and if I don't
   display a message, the cache is not invalidated.

**Are there more tricks to invalidate the broser cache /make sure the ajax request really goes to the server?**

If someone want't to try it our, here is a sample code for the `onbeforeunload`. In your network tracer tool (e.g Fiddler) you will se that the request is send to the server when the user navigates to the page with the back button. If you coment `return 'Hello world';` you won't. (Note that you will see it in your browser debugger network tracer in both cases, but this is not represential for waht is actually send to the server).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>onbeforeunload</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>    
    <a href="http://google.com">Link away</a>
    <script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return 'Hello world';
        } 


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test", //doesn't matter if it is invalid
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add timestamp to ajax request in jquery like this

```
data: { 'time': new Date().getTime() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add cache:false to the ajax call to prevent caching

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test", //doesn't matter if it is invalid
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

This works by adding and &_=timestamp to the end of the request. While it forces a new request to be sent to the server which is what you are after. It also has a side effect of adding the request to the browsers cache. So if you are making lots of these request it can pollute the cache with lots of little ajax requests.

Comment: np. I actually expected this answer a few times. Hope the final solution will be that simple too :D